# createCompatNavigationProp example?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to use the compatibility helper `createCompatNavigationProp` from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/compatibility/ but I don't know how to use it.

This is the function if it helps: https://github.com/react-navigation/navigation-ex/blob/master/packages/compat/src/createCompatNavigationProp.tsx